# All separation axioms are preserved under disjoint union?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Given topological space $\{ (X_{i},O_{i}) \}_{i\in I}$, we can form their disjoint union $X := \amalg_{i}X_{i}$. Now if each $(X_{i},O_{i})$ satisfy the same separation axiom ($T_{0}, T_{1}, T_{2}, T_{2 \frac{1}{2}}, T_{3}, T_{3 \frac{1}{2}}, T_{4}, T_{5}, T_{6}$), I think so does their disjoint union

I think for $T_{6}$, we can use the pasting lemma(or by the universal construction). Given disjoint closed set $A,B \subset X$, for any $i$, $A_{i}:=A\cap X_{i}$ and $B_{i}:=B\cap X$ are both closed, so there exists continuous $f_{i}:X_{i} \to \mathbb{R}$ on $X_{i}$ that exactly separate $A_{i}$ and $B_{i}$, define $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f: (i,x (\in X_{i})) \mapsto f_{i}(x)$, then by pasting lemma(or the universal construction of disjoint union) $f$ is continuous.

I think the other ones are true as well, but will be too much to write down.

> So are all these separation axioms preserved under disjoint union? Perhaps there is a quick way to see that they all hold? Or maybe there's a counterexample?

I know there are wiki posts such that all separation axioms are preserved under homeomorphisms, and I hope this post can serve as a confirmation or to show a counterexample for future readers. (If it seems true, I will maybe write down all cases when I get a chance)

Comment: I guess I forgot to write completely Hausdorff in the list.

Comment: So do you want us to write down something that is too much for you to write down? Why don't you work through it for yourself and post again here if there is a case that troubles you?

Comment: @RobArthan No, I think I have all of them in my mind. Many are quite trivial, but maybe I missed something. I just want some confirmation or perhaps it would be nice if someone knew whether there's a quick way to see all of them are true. If there's no counterexample appearing, I might type all of them out when I got a chance.

Comment: If you want to self-answer this I could see there being some value in having a general resource available for people to cite.  If you decide to do so, my suggestion is you begin with a clear statement of basic facts about disjoint unions ($A\subseteq \amalg X_i$ is open/closed iff $A\cap X_i$ is open/closed for each $i$, function $f\colon \amalg X_i\to Z$ is continuous iff continuous when restricted to each $X_i$).  Then the proofs mostly become one or two liners by citing above facts, sometimes with two cases depending on whether points being separated are in same $X_i$.

Comment: Also, you mentioned the separation properties being preserved under homeomorphisms - that really does not require separate proofs - they are all properties stated in terms of open and closed sets, it is immediate from their definitions that they are topological properties, so in my view proving ***that*** explicitly would indeed be going too far and a complete waste of time.

Comment: @MW Yeah, I will self-answer that when I get a chance. Based on what you said I guess this [list](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Separation_Axioms_Preserved_under_Homeomorphism) is indeed going too far.